# Swift Windows arc4random

Tags: swift, windows

Hi I am currently learning Swift and my operating system is Windows and using Visual Studio. What can I use instead of `arc4random_uniform` which is not working right now ? I tried to `import Foundation` Library but still did not work. Thank you.

*`Int.random ()` also does not work.

Comment: [`Int.random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random)?

Comment: yes I tried it it gave me this error " type 'Int' has no member 'random' "

Comment: I tried  let numbers = random(in: 1...10)  and I got an error "use of unresolved identifier 'random' and "did you mean rand?" then I tried   let numbers = rand(in: 1...10) and I got another error "argument passed to call that takes no arguments". And finally I tried let numbers = rand()  and I could generate random numbers but this time I can't give a range. Thank you for help.

Comment: The syntax is `let number = Int.random(in: 1...10)`. Works fine in Windows. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72079165/1271826).

Answer (score 0):

The Swift equivalent to `arc4random_uniform` is [`Int.random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random). E.g., consider:

```swift
print("hello, world")

let value = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
print(value)
```

This works on Windows without any problem:

```
C:\...\>swiftc --version
compnerd.org Swift version 5.6.1 (swift-5.6.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc

C:\...\>set SWIFTFLAGS=-sdk %SDKROOT% -I %SDKROOT%\usr\lib\swift -L %SDKROOT%\usr\lib\swift\windows

C:\...\>swiftc test.swift -emit-executable %SWIFTFLAGS% -o test.exe
   Creating library test.lib and object test.exp

C:\...\>test
hello, world
42
```

---

If this is not working for you, I might advise checking your Swift version. It worked with 5.6.1 installed from [here](https://www.swift.org/download/) following [these instructions](https://www.swift.org/getting-started/#on-windows) on Windows 10.